# How to add class files and folders to a jar file from a directory in Java

Tags: java, swing

Hello people of stackoverflow :)

Today i have come across a problem which i need some help fixing.

I want to get the contents of a folder from my computer then add that contents into a jar file replacing any existing files already in that jar file. I am attempting to do this from within a java program.

I already wrote a method that will extract the contents of the jar file but i came up that this will be a faster and much more efficient method for what i have to do.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the jar-file with WinRar or 7Zip.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Create a normal executable jar? You don't need a method to extract the contents of a jar. Just extract the file with a decompressor.

Comment: I am trying to edit an already executable jar with files from a folder on my computer, but i want to do this through a piece of code in my application.

Comment: Are you trying to [update the JAR containing the class file which you are currently running](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6477318/230513)?

Comment: No i am trying to edit an already existing jar file by adding in file from a directory on my computer. In my actual application their will be an option to choose what directory you wish the files to be added from.

Comment: I still need help with this if anybody can help me, It will help me out a lot with my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried looking into the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from a Java application, you can consider  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command")`

Comment: Even if i did this, i don't know of a way to add files from a directory to an already existing jar file.