# FileSystem error when trying to close it

Tags: java, jar, nio

Currently I'm trying to make a level editor for a Java game that I created.
My problem is that my program doesn't save the edited levels.

Here is the code that I made so far:

```
Path path = Paths.get(gameFile.getAbsolutePath());
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null);
Path p = fs.getPath("rpg"+fs.getSeparator()+"levels"+fs.getSeparator()+"level"+(short)level+".png");
OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(p);
ImageIO.write(img, "png", os);
os.close();
fs.close();
```

`gameFile` is the .jar file of my game which contains the levels and 
the levels are saved as .png files.
I have tried to save my picture outside of the jar and it worked so i guess i made a mistake with the FileSystem or the Path.
The Path in the jar is rpg/levels/level*.png

Edit:
I changed

```
OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(p);
```

to

```
OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(p,StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

but now I get an error when closing the fileSystem

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: G:\RPG.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.sync(ZipFileSystem.java:1294)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:277)
at de.jorolf.editor.LevelEditor$5.actionPerformed(LevelEditor.java:213)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save anything inside of a **running** `jar-File` (related: [updating-a-jar-whilst-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477318/updating-a-jar-whilst-running)).

Also, if you want to save something inside of a **not running** `jar-File`, then you also need to save the file compressed. For this task you can simply add a `ZipOutputStream` to your stream-queue (Java-Doc: [ZipOutputStream.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)). Also `java.util.jar.JarFile` and `java.util.jar.JarEntry` may be helpful.

For your general task, you should save the level file outside of the `jar`. You may distribute the game in a folder `game` with `/game/theGame.jar` and `/game/firstLevel.lvl`. Then the level is outside of the jar and you can modify it.

Also you may use common directories as other games do, like Windows `Documents` or `AppData` for game specific settings and data.

`MyDocuments` in Java: `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getPath()`
`AppData` in Java: `System.getenv("APPDATA")`

Comment: If I would save my levels in MyDocuments or AppData it would be bound to a specific computer, but I want the game to be like 'plug & play'. I tried using ZipOutputStream but it deletes all my files that were previously in my jar file

Comment: You can extract the whole archive via `ZipInputStream`, modify and then recreate the archive with `ZipOutputStream`, just google around *java how to modify a jar*. But I'd recommend to use the first option. Use a folder **"MyGame"** which contains the `jar` and resource folders. Then you are able to fully control the resources as they are outside of the jar itself.

Comment: As said before, the class `JarFile` may be very helpful for changing the contents of a `jar-File`. Here's the doc: [JarFile.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html)

Comment: I would use JarFile but i dont see how i could add files to that. I can get an entry, but if it doesnt exist I just an an error.

Comment: Here's some code to add files to a jar-File: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1281295/2411243

Comment: My problem is that the `JarOutputStream` doesn't contain the files that are in the jar File. I tried to add them by making a `JarFile` and getting all the entries by going trough a `Enumeration` but I get a `java.util.zip.ZipError` when calling the function `nextElement()`.

Comment: You may create a new question for this problem. It appears to be too complex for solving it in the comment section and it differs from the initial question/problem :)